# Getting javassist class with playframework

Tags: java, reflection, playframework, javassist

I'm trying to obtain CtClass reference to my model class. I started with simpliest version 
`ClassPool.getDefault().get(className);` and it worked fine. But only on my machine. It doesn't work on server.

Anyway i think that the version shouldn't work because Playframework stores classes in tmp/classses. So by now i finished with this version:

```
ClassPool pool = new ClassPool();
pool.appendClassPath(Play.applicationPath + "/tmp/classes");
CtClass cls = pool.get(className);
```

But i am not sure about this version. Will it work always? Are there better options?

I also tried using ClassClassPath and LoaderClassPath but without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you should not touch javassist class unless you are writing plugin and need to enhance the application code. in which case, you will have a `MyPluginEnhancer extends play.classloading.enhancers.Enhancer`, then you can get the javassist class instance by calling `makeClass(ApplicationClass appClass)` method.

For a workable example, please refer to https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-morphia/blob/master/src/play/modules/morphia/MorphiaEnhancer.java.

PS: About `play.classloading.enhancers.Enhancer.makeClass` method implementation

```
/**
 * Construct a javassist CtClass from an application class.
 */
public CtClass makeClass(ApplicationClass applicationClass) throws IOException {
    return classPool.makeClass(new ByteArrayInputStream(applicationClass.enhancedByteCode));
}
```

Where `classPool` comes from the following code:

```
public Enhancer() {
    this.classPool = newClassPool();
}

public static ClassPool newClassPool() {
    ClassPool classPool = new ClassPool();
    classPool.appendSystemPath();
    classPool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(Enhancer.class.getClassLoader()));
    classPool.appendClassPath(new ApplicationClassesClasspath());
    return classPool;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Well thanks for telling that i should avoid using it ;) I need CtClass to read configuration from annotations and standard java.reflection doesn't deliver what i need.